# Fibonacci nim winning strategies in different situations

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Rules of fibonacci nim:

Fibonacci nim is played by two players, who alternate removing coins or other counters from a pile. On the first move, a player is not allowed to take all of the coins, and on each subsequent move, the number of coins removed can be any number that is at most twice the previous move. According to the normal play convention, the player who takes the last coin wins.

And i have to show this 4 things:

1)prove that if on the beginning of the game on the table is $2F_n$ coins, then winning move is to take $F_{n-2}$ coins

2)designate winning move if on the beginning of the game on the table is $F_n-1$ coins

3)prove that if on the beginning of the game on the table is $F_n^2$ coins, then taking 1 coin is winning move

4)designate winning move if on the beginning of the game on the table is $4F_n$ coins

And we have that $F_0=1, F_1=2$ and then $F_n=F_{n-2}+F_{n-1}$

I know what is the winning strategy in fibonacci nim game, but i dont know how find zeckendorf representation of numbers in point $1-4$ :(

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Zeckendorf representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem) of positive integers and its [relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_nim#Strategy) with Fibonacci nim?

Comment: I know what is the winning strategy, but how to find the Zeckendorf distribution, e.g. the number $2F_n$

Comment: Okay. I’ve not had a chance to think seriously about it yet, but I wanted to find out how much background we had to work with.

Comment: If you know the winning strategy, and you only want to find Zeckendorf representation of numbers in your questions, why didn't you ask for that? You could have put additional information on why you want to find Z. representation by adding this game as a background. Or if you are unsure that finding Z. representation will lead to the answer to your original question, at least add in the body of the question what you know about it and why you think it might be helpful for this question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $(1)$ note that $2F_n=F_n+(F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})=(F_{n+1}-F_{n-1})+(F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})$.

For $(2)$ prove by induction that

$$F_n-1=F_{n-1}+F_{n-3}+F_{n-5}+\ldots+F_m=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1}F_{n-(2k+1)}\;,$$

where

$$m=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
2,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

For $(3)$ I note the following Zeckendorf representations:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|r}
n&F_n^2&\text{Zeckendorf}\\\hline
1&1&1\\
2&1&\color{red}{1}\\
3&4&101\\
4&9&\color{red}{10001}\\
5&25&1000101\\
6&64&\color{red}{100010001}\\
7&169&10001000101\\
8&441&\color{red}{1000100010001}\\
9&1156&100010001000101
\end{array}$$

This shows a pattern that suggests that $F_{n+2}^2=F_n^2+F_{2n+2}$, and this, if true, would allow an easy inductive proof of the claim. In fact this is an old identity due to Lucas; there is an easy combinatorial proof in [this PDF](http://www.m-hikari.com/imf-2010/17-20-2010/krzywkowskiIMF17-20-2010.pdf) (Theorem $4$).

For $(4)$, similar experimentation with the Zeckendorf representations of the numbers $4F_n$ will suggest an identity for $4F_n$ that yields a strategy for $n\ge 3$.

Comment: Thank you tomorrow I will check if I understand everything and if I have a problem I will write :)

Comment: @TuptuśTupta: You’re welcme.

Comment: to be honest I don't understand how to find a pattern from this table. I know how the table was created but if you did not write what is the relationship between the numbers I would not have figured it out myself. Could you explain how step by step you came up with an example?

Comment: @TuptuśTupta: For $(3)$, or for $(4)$?

Comment: @TuptuśTupta: For $(3)$ I noticed that the Zeckendorf representation of $F_{n+2}^2$ just adds a prefix $1000$ to the Zeckendorf representation of $F_n^2$. This means that $F_{n+2}^2=F_n^2+F_m$ for some $m$. Looking at the table, I see that $m$ increases by $2$ when $n$ increases by $1$, so that $m=2n+k$ for some $k$, and after that it was just a matter of finding $k$ by inspecting the table.

Comment: Ok i understand, but $F_{n+2}^2=F_n^2+F_{2n+2}$ isn't the Zeckendorf distribution of the number $F_n ^2$

Comment: @TuptuśTupta: Look at the table: that identity makes it possible to prove by induction that if the Zeck. rep. of $F_n^2$ ends in $1$, so does the Zeck. rep. of $F_{n+2}^2$, and that allows you to conclude from the known winning strategy that you should take one coin.

Comment: I do point $4$ using property $F_n=F_{n+1}-F_{n-1}$ and I get $4F_n=F_{n-2}+F_n+F_{n+2}$. Is there an easier way to solve task 3? One that would give us a Zeckendorf distribution with the smallest word F_1 or F_2? Or could you prove that $F_{n+2}^2=F_n^2+F_{2n+2}$

Comment: @TuptuśTupta: Yes, that’s the same solution that I got for $(4)$. In $(3)$ you don’t need the actual distribution: you just need to prove that the Zeck. rep. of each $F_n^2$ ends in $1$. There may be better ways, but the easiest one that I found was to use the identity $F_{n+2}^2=F_n^2+F_{2n+2}$ to prove it by induction. A proof of that identity is in the PDF to which I linked in my answer.

Comment: So if i have $F_{n+2}^2=F_n^2+F_{2n+2}$ how now show that every $F_n^2$ have number $1$ in zeckendorf distribution?

Comment: @Piszczu: The Zeck. reps. of $F_1^2$ and $F_2^2$ end in $1$. Show that $F_{2n+2}$ is substantially bigger than $F_n^2$ — the table suggests that if $F_k$ is the largest Fibonacci number in the Zeck. rep. of $F_n^2$, then $2n+2=k+4$ — and it will be immediate that the Zeck. rep. of $F_{n+2}^2$ simply adds a $1$ and some $0$s to the left of the Zeck. rep. of $F_n^2$. Thus, if the Zeck. rep. of $F_n^2$ ends in $1$, so does that of $F_{n+1}^2$.

Comment: ok but how to show that $2n+2=k+4$? I see it from the table but how to prove it?

Comment: @Piszczu: All that you really need is that $F_{2n+2}<F_{n+2}^2<F_{2n+3}$; one approach might be to use the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding) that $F_n$ is the integer nearest $\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}$.